# How to adjust the size of EC key in Python?

Tags: python, serialization, cryptography, ecdh

I generate a private and public key using this.

```
private_key_alice = ec.generate_private_key(curve=ec.SECP256R1(),backend=default_backend())
public_key_alice = private_key_alice.public_key()
```

And then I serialise it so I can have it in hexadecimal as follows.

```
serialized_public = public_key_alice.public_bytes(encoding=serialization.Encoding.X962,format=serialization.PublicFormat.UncompressedPoint)
print(serialized_public.decode('latin1'))
hex_string2=serialized_public.decode('latin1')
hex_string2_hex = hex_string2.encode().hex()
print("Hex:", hex_string2_hex)
```

But the string it generates is never 130 characters long.

```
Hex: 04c3aec297c3bf2ec39f00c3ba3dc3b10ac294c29b1b27c2b163032cc2b11946c2a735c295c38ec3ae36c2a309c299c2894b4144c39801c3a62479487256c3bdc2adc2a450c2b85f28c2acc3adc2a87ec381c2bd654d0325c2b0234163c39e
```

How can I make it 130 characters without losing information?

Comment: Your code does not run, because `hex_string2` is not defined. You probably mean `hex_string2 = serialized_public.decode('latin1')`, at least this way your issue can be reproduced.

Comment: The reason for your corrupted key is that you first decode the data with `latin1`, then encode it with the default encoding, i.e. UTF-8, and finally hex encode the result. A correct hex encoding is simply done with `serialized_public.hex()`. This gives the expected 130 hex digits (for secp256r1).

Comment: I have this `hex_string2 = serialized_public.decode('latin1')` and it still doesn't work. And if I set it to UTF-8 it tells me `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa4 in position 3: invalid start byte`

Comment: Have you tried `serialized_public.hex()`?